# How to present an ISO 8601 time string more readably

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, datetime-format

I have an Oracle 12c database column called "lag_time" which is VARCHAR2, with values in the following format:

| lag_time |
| --- |
| PT2H16M33S |
| PT11H40M12S |
| PT11M33S |
| P17DT12H32M47S |
| P233DT11H21M54S |
| PT10M28S |
| .... |
| .... |

I need some suggestions and solutions on how to present this in a more readable way - preferably as total minutes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `to_dsinterval()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DSINTERVAL.html#GUID-DEBB41BD-9438-4558-A53E-428CE93C05D3) to convert your strings to intervals:

```
to_dsinterval(lag_time)
```

And you can then extract the various elements, multiply each of them to get the equivalent minute value, and add them together; for complete minutes:

```
select lag_time, lag_interval,
  (extract(day from lag_interval) * 1440)
  + (extract(hour from lag_interval) * 24)
  + extract(minute from lag_interval) as total_minutes
from (
  select lag_time, to_dsinterval(lag_time) as lag_interval
  from your_table
)
```

| LAG_TIME | LAG_INTERVAL | TOTAL_MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PT2H16M33S | +000000000 02:16:33.000000000 | 64 |
| PT11H40M12S | +000000000 11:40:12.000000000 | 304 |
| PT11M33S | +000000000 00:11:33.000000000 | 11 |
| P17DT12H32M47S | +000000017 12:32:47.000000000 | 24800 |
| P233DT11H21M54S | +000000233 11:21:54.000000000 | 335805 |
| PT10M28S | +000000000 00:10:28.000000000 | 10 |

or to include fractional minutes:

```
select lag_time, lag_interval,
  (extract(day from lag_interval) * 1440)
  + (extract(hour from lag_interval) * 24)
  + extract(minute from lag_interval)
  + (extract(second from lag_interval) / 60) as total_minutes
from (
  select lag_time, to_dsinterval(lag_time) as lag_interval
  from your_table
)
```

| LAG_TIME | LAG_INTERVAL | TOTAL_MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PT2H16M33S | +000000000 02:16:33.000000000 | 64.55 |
| PT11H40M12S | +000000000 11:40:12.000000000 | 304.2 |
| PT11M33S | +000000000 00:11:33.000000000 | 11.55 |
| P17DT12H32M47S | +000000017 12:32:47.000000000 | 24800.78333333333333 |
| P233DT11H21M54S | +000000233 11:21:54.000000000 | 335805.9 |
| PT10M28S | +000000000 00:10:28.000000000 | 10.466666666666666667 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1132ad1f063fa3b97843c31a15054a01)

Of course, since you're storing strings you won't necessarily have valid values; you can handle that with the `default ... on conversion error` clause if you need to, but it would be better to store an actual interval value. If you really need the string value you could also add a virtual column to your table that converts it to an interval.

The column name suggests to me that you will only ever have positive values; you'd need to do a bit more work to handle negative values properly.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Alex Poole! Works like a charm! As an absolut Oracle beginner I too often find it nearly impossible to find a function which suits the purpose in different situations. stackoverflow almost always saves the day! Thanks again Alex Poole! :)